Are US enlisted personnel (as opposed to officers) required, or allowed, to disobey unlawful orders?
In a comment on Does Justice Sotomayor's "Seal Team 6" example, in and of itself, explicitly give the President the authority to execute opponents? If not, why not?, user jesse_b writes, in regard to a hypothetical order to carry out an assassination of a political rival:

as for seal team six only officers would be charged for obeying that order. Enlisted have no obligation nor option to disobey "unlawful" orders.

Is this accurate?  Please include relevant citations.

I rejected an edit to make it "commissioned officers" because I don't know whether jesse_b intended that restriction, or whether warrant / petty officers were to be included.

Possible duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/ and related https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93719/

Wouldn't part of the question be, how non-officers would even know the order is unlawful? If the order was "torture and kill small children" then of course they would know, but if the order was "this person is a terrorist threat and we must eliminate him", then how would they know whether it's true or not. Or even more general, "lay suppressive fire in that direction" (without seeing or knowing what is exactly in that direction), how would they know whether it's a legitimate target or not?

Are you suggesting that not following unlawful orders is equivalent to disobeying lawful orders?

@AndrewMorton: That's how I interpreted jesse_b's comment. I'm skeptical, which is why I asked the question.

This doesn't exactly answer the question for the US military, but as a former enlisted soldier in the Australian Army, we were explicitly taught during basic training that the "lawful order" requirement applied to us as well. We were expected to only obey lawful orders, and to disobey unlawful ones.

Edit: In his comment below, MacGuffin indicates that he received the same instruction at US Army basic training.

I'm having trouble finding a source that specifically distinguishes between Officers and Enlisted in the US context, so I think it's reasonable to assume that the US Military is similar in this regard to the Australian Defence Force. If there really was a legal requirement for enlisted personnel in the US Military to follow all orders, including illegal ones, then I expect that information would appear very quickly in a simple google search.
This article contains the following quote, which appears to imply that the "lawful order" requirement applies to everyone in the US Military.

It would be palpably illegal to give an order to torture a prisoner.  There is no defensible legal argument that interrogation techniques such as waterboarding are permitted. No soldier, sailor, or airman would be in a position to plead ignorance of the law. Any member of the military who received such an order would not just be allowed to disobey it – they would be required to do so.


I was given the same instruction during basic training as an enlisted soldier in the US Army.  I had no obligation to carry out unlawful orders.  The caveat given in basic training was that while a lowly recruit on a base in the middle of the state of Misery (some spell it "Missouri") it was unlikely any order given would have serious implications, therefore if an order didn't "smell right" we were to do as we were told then report the incident later to our chain of command.  Presumably with experience we'd learn the distinction and therefore have grounds to refuse an order later on.

From Military Justice Center

CAN YOU RECOGNIZE AN UNLAWFUL ORDER?
In the oath that service members take, they pledge to “obey the orders of the President of the United States and the orders of the officers appointed over me…” The Uniform Code of Military Justice (UCMJ) specified that they are required to obey “the lawful orders of his/her superior.”

So you're only required to obey lawful orders. The article then goes on to describe the My Lai massacre during the Viet Nam War as an example of an unlawful order. The Army commander and the men in his command who carried out this order were court martialed for their actions. Their defense was that they were just following the orders from their superiors. But since these orders were "palpably illegal", they should have refused; by obeying the orders, they were committing murder.

I'm not sure that My Lai is a good example because only one person was convicted, an officer (Lt. William Calley).  I couldn't find the complete list of defendants, but if any enlisted personnel were tried, they were acquitted.

The wording you provided "... they are required to obey 'the lawful orders of his/her superior.' " indicates that the president ordering a navy seal member to execute a political opponent would be sanctified by the Military Justice Center, because the orders themselves are lawful as SCOTUS just ruled.

@spacetyper immunity does not make all acts legal; it is protection from prosecution and punishment for committing illegal acts.

Please note that the oath is different for enlisted and officers. The version you give is the one for enlisted. The officers' oath only says "support and defend the Constitution". I understand this as meaning that officers are expected to understand the Constitution and take responsibility for evaluating the constitutionality of the orders they receive, while enlisted are not.

@spacetyper furthermore, any immunity conferred by the SCOTUS ruling would only apply to the President. Any military personnel involved could still be prosecuted for following an illegal order.

@NateEldredge Well, it's the only example they gave at the web site ("Army Lt. William Calley and some of the men in his command were court-martialed"). I guess "were court-martialed" means they were tried, but not necessarily convicted). I imagine there have been others, but I don't know where to look for them.

There is some material on My Lai here. The end of the article supports my recollection, that Calley was the only person convicted. I recall at the time that the officer commanding the enlisted men was deemed responsible, but not the man under his command. I never understood how the Captain was acquitted.

I don't see how we can even begin to consider this an adequate answer without mentioning the Geneva Convention.

@MikeB the Geneva convention is part of US law, as it was ratified by congress. Therefore no explicit mention needs be made.

@jwenting that depends on whether the Geneva convention is "self executing" which doesn't seem to be a settled question.

@MikeB the duty not to carry out an unlawful order seems not to depend on the reason for the order's unlawfulness, so mentioning the Geneva convention (or any other specific source of law) should not change the answer.

@phoog  (As you can tell) I disagree - the Geneva Convention (etc.) is a very good proxy for both domestic and international laws of combat, and allows discussion of countries other than the USA, though I do understand that most citizens of the USA don't think that any other country matters, which is rather where the question starts...

@MikeB the Geneva conventions may be relevant in determining whether a given order is unlawful.  For the purposes of this question, it is assumed that the order is unlawful, so no determination is necessary.  Discussion of whether any given order is unlawful or of the reasons for an order being unlawful is not relevant to the question.  So, not only are the Geneva conventions irrelevant here, so are other domestic and international laws of combat.  (Also this question has nothing to do with other countries, much less US citizens' understanding of their importance.)

@phoog  Tosh. As others have pointed out, if a soldier of any rank has no way of evaluating whether an order is lawful or not, then (s)he equally has no basis to reject it, either morally or legally. Since most (alleged) war crimes are carried out in other countries, I don't see how you can discount 'foreign' / international law.

@MikeB I think "lawful" must be interpreted as referring to US laws, not the country where they're fighting. SEAL Team 6 almost certainly broke some Pakistani laws when they killed Bin Laden.

In the US military services, both enlisted and officers are required to not follow unlawful orders.
That said, not following illegal orders, in the short-term most likely will not be easy, to say the least.
References:
https://www.mcmilitarylaw.com/articles-of-ucmj/article-92-failure-to-obey-an-order/
https://www.mcmilitarylaw.com/articles-of-ucmj/article-118-murder/
(@Michael, US Army and Australian Army are basically the same on this subject.)

Following orders is not a valid defense under certain laws and in certain situations even if the enlisted/officers are required to follow orders by their home country laws.
See for example the failure of the "superior orders" defense during the Nuremberg trials, Adolf Eichmann trial, and other Nazi-related trials; The trials on war crimes in the former Yugoslavia, Congo, others; and local trials (My Lai was mentioned, Kfar Qasim, and more recent examples from Iraq and Ukraine).

This doesn't necessarily rule out the existence of militaries that do require orders to be carried out.  In such a military, a soldier might have to choose between prosecution by their own military vs. prosecution by the international courts.  Fortunately it seems the US at least only requires enlisted to carry out "lawful" orders, although I don't know enough to say if there could ever be cases where the US military would consider an order lawful while international courts (especially one whose authority the US respects)  would consider the ordered act unlawful in some respect.

@PeterCordes that's true, but at least two of my examples (My Lai and Abu Ghraib) are examples of the US military prosecuting its own soldiers (including enlisted) for following unlawful orders. There are definitely militaries that don't consider unlawful things that we do - Russia (the Ukrainian example) is one such military. It may in some cases be a trolley problem, especially at war time when refusing to carry out orders may be considered treasonous and punishable by death - in some militaries that would be just an immediate execution by the commanding officer, again see the Soviets in WW2

Sure, the situation I proposed can still have orders that both courts consider illegal, like the examples you cite for any sane country.  I was thinking of issues where a country is at odds with an international court but hasn't stopped recognizing its authority.  (Or more realistically, the soldier has to guess the winning side in a war to decide whose rules to follow for long-term safety from prosecution... But getting shot in the short term is very possible if we're considering draconian military rules.  Heh, your comment edit added the same thought.)

One reason that the superior orders defense failed for Nazis (it was a valid and effective defense until then) is to deter future behavior. Basically everyone was convicted, from the highest of the command (including Eichmann) until the last of the still living guards in their deep 90s... (IIRC just recently one was convicted in Germany). The point is to not only punish, but to deter, and to make officers and soldiers think twice before doing something blatantly awful. I'm glad to see that the Western militaries did learn the lesson.

@littleadv  "I'm glad to see that the Western militaries did learn the lesson." - Citation needed. Plenty of examples of dubious behaviour that has been hushed up.

The Nuremberg trials are extremely shady. Mind I'm not defending the actions of the convicted there, but they were convicted under laws that were put in place AFTER they had committed the acts for which they were convicted. That's explicitly prohibited under pretty much any legal system (including the US system).

Sometimes people can't anticipate how bad human nature can be. Lack of written laws is not an excuse for what the Nazis did. As to the dubious behaviors - sure, Americans nuked two cities, napalmed another country, and wars are still vicious - human nature didn't change. But at least some laws did.

Depends on what you mean by "allowed". I'm not a lawyer of any kind, but I can tell you from experience that while your oath only requires you to follow lawful orders and we were taught the same while enlisted, if you disobey ANY order, lawful or not, you're in for a world of sh**.
How you get handled will heavily depend on the circumstances, like who's prosecuting you and what the order was. For example, an officer ordering you to vote for a particular presidential candidate is unlawful but much different than say, ordering you to drop bombs on your own base during your next sortie. You will likely not go to jail or lose stripes for refusing the latter order and the officer who gave it would likely end up in prison, but the former might earn the officer a reprimand and maybe a small demotion (depending on their record), but you may still receive some retaliation...
Obviously they can't come after you for disobeying the order after that case is settled, but they can and likely will come after you for literally anything else they can conjure up and usually some variation of finding a dereliction of duty in some unrelated context. For example, late for duty, shoddy work, behavior unbecoming of an NCO, etc. they'll find something and there is almost guaranteed to be some regulation they can pin to your chest. No really. I've watched it happen a hundred times. Even saw an NCO lose 3 stripes and had his re-enlistment denied because his wife got a DUI (off base). That has nothing to do with him at all, but they made it stick, and it was in retaliation for refusing an order to work over 14 hours on the flightline stateside (which is a technical order from the DoD which says you're a danger to yourself and everyone around you after 12 hours). This is super common in the Air Force, I'm not sure about other branches.
